# Asp.net grid view column count

Tags: asp.net

I am  using asp.net with vb. Here i bind data to Gridview. This Dataset has 5 records with 3 columns and also gridview shows that 5 records with 3 columns. But Gridview.columns.count property return 0. i want to get that colunm count. please help me sir.

```
    dim lcolumncount as integer
    GridView1.DataSource = ExecuteDataSet("Select Master_TypeID,Master_TypeName,Master_TrimName from Mastertype")
    GridView1.DataBind()

lcolumncount = Gridview.columns.count
```

here always lcolumncount rerurn 0. i want 3.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the row to count first

```
GridView1.Rows(0).Cells.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo in your code - you're binding the DataSet to Gridview1 but getting the column count from Gridview (without the 1).

Comment: ya. Any another way to get column count from gridview.?

Answer (score 1):

At exactly which point are you calling DataBind() and then trying to access the column count? Your code is messed up so i suspect that you are not getting the column count immediately after binding.

With your code you posted, you are using `GridView1`, but when accessing the column count you are using `GridView` (without the `1`), which makes me think your code copy & paste is a little inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
dim lcolumncount as integer
GridView1.DataSource = ExecuteDataSet("Select Master_TypeID,Master_TypeName,Master_TrimName from Mastertype")
GridView1.DataBind()

lcolumncount = Gridview.columns.count
```

Comment: this never works!. its always cells that get counted per row on a gridview!

Answer (score 0):

`lcolumncount = Gridview.columns.count(0)` will return the total count of fields in the grid both visible and invisible.

But `lcolumncount = Gridview.DisplayedColumnCount(0)` returns only the number of fields that are shown.

Answer (score 0):

lcolumncount = Gridview.columns.GetColumnCount(0) will return total counts of fields in the grid visible and invisible included.

lcolumncount = Gridview.DisplayedColumnCount(0)
 Returns only the number of fields that are shown.

Good luck